# Laravel 4.2 DB returning all records

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am using Laravel 4.2 and catching single data from DB, because foreach loop is giving me last record all time

This is foreach in my blade.php file:

```
    @foreach($vrataMreze as $vrataMrezeVar)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $vrataMrezeVar->nalogBroj }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vrataMrezeVar->nazivNaloga }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vrataMrezeVar->narucitelj }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vrataMrezeVar->datumIzrade }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vrataMrezeVar->statusProizvodnje }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vrataMrezeVar->datumOtpreme }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vrataMrezeVar->nacinOtpreme }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vrataMrezeVar->statusPoslovnice }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vrataMrezeVar->datumMontaze }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vrataMrezeVar->montirano }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vrataMrezeVar->isporuceno }}</td>
            <td align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
            <td align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
            <td align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></td>
            <td align="center"><a href="{{ URL::route('openVrataMreza', $vrataMrezeVar->id);  }} " target="_blank" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a></td>                                         
        </tr>
```

Route for this action:

```
Route::get('/nalozi/mreze/vrataMrezaOpen', array('uses' => 'MrezeController@openVrataMreza', 'as' => 'openVrataMreza'));
```

And function from my controller:

```
public function openVrataMreza($id)
    {
        $vrataMreze = DB::table('VrataMreza')->where('id', $id)->first();
        return View::make('nalozi.Mreze.Vrata_Mreze.vrataMrezaOpen')->with('vrataMreze', $vrataMreze);
    }
```

Also I tried with

```
 Session::set('id', $vrataMrezeVar->id);
```

and

```
 Session::get('id');
```

but didn't work, aslo get last record from database..

Comment: basic debugging,d id you check `var_dump($vrataMreze)` to confirm it contains what you think it does?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not much clear , but to get last record you can modify eloquent query.

```
 public function openVrataMreza($id)
{
    $vrataMreze = DB::table('VrataMreza')->where('id', $id)->orderBy('id','DESC')->first();
    return View::make('nalozi.Mreze.Vrata_Mreze.vrataMrezaOpen')->with('vrataMreze', $vrataMreze);
}
```